# Android resource management

Tags: android, scheduling

Sorry if this is naive, but is there any good documents on how the Android OS manages resources? I mean if more than 1 app asks to use a bunch of resources (say network/GPS), how is it decided which task gets access? I understand that the CPU scheduler is CFS/BFS, I'm trying to understand how sensor use is regulated. Thanks!